# Determine the following subsets of R3 are subspaces of R3. If so, give a proof, and if not, explain why.

Tags: linear-algebra

U1={(x, y, 1)|x, y are real numbers}

U2={(a, a - b, b)|a, b are real numbers}

U3={(r, s, t)|r, s, t are non-negative numbers}

For U1:

According to the Zero Vector: $\lt x, y, 1\gt \neq \lt 0, 0, 0\gt$

According to Under Addition: $\lt 0, 0, 1\gt + \lt 0, 0, 1\gt = \lt 0, 0, 2\gt$ Not a part of the set
This is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

For U2:

According to the Zero Vector: $\lt a, a-b, b\gt = \lt 0, 0, 0\gt$

According to Under Addition $\lt 0, 0, 0\gt + \lt 0, 0, 0\gt = \lt 0, 0, 0\gt$

This is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

With U3 however, (0,0,0) can work, but in order for the statement to be correct r, s, & t would all have to be greater than or equal to 0. I can use the obvious Zero Vector method, but what about Under Addition or Under Multiplication?

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Do you know what it means for a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ to be a *subspace*? If not, look it up in your notes or whatever you're studying from. For each of these subsets, try carefully checking if each requirement for it to be a subspace holds. If you get stuck on anything specific doing that, you can ask a question about it. Just get your hands dirty a bit first!

Comment: I figured I should just ask for help was all. Even looking through my notes it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: It's OK if it doesn't make sense, but please just tell us specifically what doesn't make sense and show what you tried! A subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R^3$ will be a subspace if a) $0 \in U$, and b) whenever $x \in U$ and $y \in U$, we have $x + y \in U$ and c) whenever $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ and $x \in U$, we have $\lambda x \in U$. (There are some other, allegedly shorter, characterisations.) Can you write down whether or not you think each of these conditions holds for each of your subsets?

Comment: You will also need to show closure under scalar multiplication for part 2 (for part 1 it is enough to find one reason why the subset is *not* a subspace).  Keep scalar multiplication in mind when you try part 3, but your partial work is correct (non-negative entries are closed under vector addition and the zero vector is included).

Answer (score 1):

$U_1$ isn't a subspace because it doesn't contain the zero vector.

$U_2=\rm {span}\{(1,1,0),(0,-1,1)\}$, and is thus a subspace.

$U_3$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Linear algebra can be a bit tricky when it first comes to learning subsets, but if you understand the axiomatic approach, then it becomes much clearer.

As stated in the comments, a subset $U⊆R^3$ will be a subspace if $a) 0∈U$, and b) whenever $x∈U$ and $y∈U$, we have $x+y∈U$ and c) whenever $λ∈R$ and $x∈U$, we have $λx∈U$.

In other words, $U$ must be equal to trivial solution of $(0,0,0)$ since its in $R^3$. And there must be closure under multiplication and addition by the other two axioms.

All three axioms must be true for $U$ to be a subspace. If you notice that the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$ is not equal to $U$, since $U$ = {$(x,y,1)$ for some $x,y$ real numbers}. Meaning, no $x$ and $y$ can make $U$ = {$(0,0,0)$} And so, $U$ is not a subspace of $R^3$.

After checking the first axiom, check for closure.

Closure under addition states that $m,n∈W$, then $m+n∈W$.

Closure under multiplication states that $m,n∈W$, then $mn∈W$.

By closure under multiplication, you want to see if scalar multiples of $m,n$ will be elements of $W$. So, if any scalar $c$ is multiplied by $m,n$, then you need to check if $cm$ or $cn$ will satisfy the conditions of the set $W$. So, if $W$ has the condition that elements must have non-negative numbers, then it won't be closed under multiplication since $c$ can be any scalar, so it could be negative. And so, multiplication of elements of $W$ with a negative $c$ value will give you a negative number, not satisfying conditions of $W$.

To see if $m+n∈W$ and $mn∈W$ hold, you must check to see the conditions of the set $W$. So, if $W$ has the condition that $m,n∈W$, such that $m$ and $n$ are real numbers, then you need to check if $m+n∈W$ and $mn∈W$ will give real numbers too and thus, be elements of $W$.

Hope this helps you get started. (I haven't done linear algebra in a while so if any one notices any error on my part, then feel free too comment or imporve the post)

Comment: I just edited my post. Am I on the right track or is there still more that needs to be done?

Comment: It's good that you have worked with the trivial solution! Now you if that axiom holds, you want to move onto the next axioms for closure under addition and multiplication. Have you learnt spanning sets and linear dependence yet?

Comment: Maybe try https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/subspace-basis/v/linear-subspaces

Comment: Just updated the post, I will need help on U3 since I'm a little lost on how to get the statement correct.

Comment: I made edits and explained it in the post.